# NHibernate.Caches.SysCache version issues with Nhibernate 2.1.0 branch

Tags: nhibernate

We've branched NH 2.0.1 for some minor changes and that worked fine.  Our upgrade to 2.1.0 has dll issues with NHibernate.Caches.SysCache being built against a different NH.  My main question is how do best deal with this?  Can I use some type of assembly mapping, or is there source code I can use to build against?

Here is the error:
"Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=2.1.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)".

If we comment out the reference in the web.config, this works otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in your web.config:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate"
                              publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.1.0.4000"
                             newVersion="X.X.X.X" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

by replacing `X.X.X.X` by the version you gave to your build.

Remark: If the new version of the assembly is not signed using the same key, the binding redirect won't work. If this is the case you have no choice but to recompile `NHibernate.Caches.SysCache` against your custom NHibernate build.

---

UPDATE:

It seems that the [private key](https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate.snk) is included in the repository so you should be good to go :-)

Comment: Had no idea that I had to sign with a private key.  That was all I needed, nice work.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new version of NH Caches available that's built against NH 2.1:
http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/07/19/nhibernate-caches-2-1-0ga.html

Comment: Private key signing is really all I needed for 2.1, but for 2.1.1 I used the method Darin Listed above